# C# inheritance and overriding base properties

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

I currently have a need for a custom `ListViewItem` class - let's call it `MyListViewItem`.  It needs to have some additional data associated with each item, and perform some operations when the Checked property is changed.  I've tried several things, but currently the relevant code looks like this:

```
class MyListViewItem : ListViewItem {
    new public bool Checked {
        get {
            return base.Checked;
        }
        set {
            base.Checked = value;
            // do some other things here based on value
        }
    }
    public MyListViewItem(Object otherData) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I click on the item's checkbox in the ListView, my setter is never called.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  I'm aware that I could use the ItemChecked event of the parent ListView, but that seems like a much less clean solution.  (Also I'm not actually passing an Object to the constructor, but that part isn't important here).

Comment: Well, if anyone is interested, I ended up handling the interaction between my data and the Checked property in the getter/setter for the custom data.  Not sure why I didn't think of that before.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not working cause the "new" keyword doesn't override it just "hides".

This means that if you call Checked on an instance of object that is referenced through the type definition of MyListViewItem you *will* run your code. However the ListView references to this object via the type definition of ListViewItem and therefore will not call your "new" method.

"new" is *not* override. The better solution is to probably handle the code in a custom list view. It isn't really that ugly.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing in the list_ItemChecked handler.  I don't think it warrants a custom ListView, so I'll just look at base.Checked before I want to do anything with my custom item data.  Thanks.

Comment: [Great Article on this subject](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/10/understanding-c-using-virtual.html)

Answer (score 9):

[`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645625(VS.71).aspx) does not `override` the `base` member. It declares a new method with the same name. In VB.NET it's called `Shadows`.

Indeed, `new` doesn't do anything except turning off a compiler warning. The member you do not declare as `override` (and you can only do this if the `base` member is `virtual` or `override`) will be completely unrelated to the inheritance tree of the `base` member.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the `ListViewItem`.`Checked` property is virtual, you need to override it:

```
public override bool Checked
```

Comment: It's not virtual.  I guess I will just have to do something else.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The ListViewItem.Checked property is not virtual (see MSDN doc [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.checked.aspx)) so you will not be able to override the behavior of it in this way.  You will have to use the event or derive from ListView and override [ListView.OnItemChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.onitemcheck.aspx) to change the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your own custom ListViewItem, why not create a seperate type to contain your custom data and then assign each ListViewItem Tag property with a reference to the custom data?

This is the pattern that I've been using for some time and it works very well. As for custom action when items are checked, simply handle the relevant events in the list view.